# Issue while Liferay application startup

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am receiving the below error when I am trying to startup tomcat and deploy my war files on liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2 bundle after I migrated the DB from oracle to mysql 8.

```
09:18:23,351 ERROR [http-bio-8100-exec-1][MainServlet:1224] com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.liferay.portal.events.ServicePreAction.run(ServicePreAction.java:1295)
        at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorImpl.processEvent(EventsProcessorImpl.java:81)
        at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorImpl.process(EventsProcessorImpl.java:58)
        at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorUtil.process(EventsProcessorUtil.java:40)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.processServicePre(MainServlet.java:1204)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:501)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:294)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:187)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.isLayoutFriendliable(PortalImpl.java:4909)
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getLayoutFriendlyURL(PortalImpl.java:2448)
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getLayoutURL(PortalImpl.java:2687)
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getLayoutFullURL(PortalImpl.java:2499)
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getLayoutFullURL(PortalImpl.java:2492)
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getLayoutFullURL(PortalImpl.java:2580)
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getLayoutFullURL(PortalUtil.java:721)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(ServiceContextFactory.java:69)
        at com.liferay.portal.events.ServicePreAction.servicePre(ServicePreAction.java:1949)
        at com.liferay.portal.events.ServicePreAction.run(ServicePreAction.java:1292)
        ... 119 more
09:18:23,400 ERROR [http-bio-8100-exec-2][error_jsp:422] User ID null
09:18:23,402 ERROR [http-bio-8100-exec-2][error_jsp:423] Current URL /group/kir
09:18:23,402 ERROR [http-bio-8100-exec-2][error_jsp:424] Referer null
09:18:23,403 ERROR [http-bio-8100-exec-2][error_jsp:425] Remote address 10.11.11.1
09:18:23,403 ERROR [http-bio-8100-exec-2][error_jsp:427] com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.liferay.portal.events.ServicePreAction.run(ServicePreAction.java:1295)
        at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorImpl.processEvent(EventsProcessorImpl.java:81)
        at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorImpl.process(EventsProcessorImpl.java:58)
        at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorUtil.process(EventsProcessorUtil.java:40)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.processServicePre(MainServlet.java:1204)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:501)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        ers.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
       ost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:216)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Environment Details -

> Jdk1.8
>       MySql8.0,
>       liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2,
>       Tomcat 7,
>       All default configurations

Here is the link of the same issue on liferay community : [Liferay Community](https://community.liferay.com/es/forums/-/message_boards/message/111207923)

Can anyone please guide me here .

Comment: liferay-portal-6.1.1 runs well with Jdk 1.6 / 1.7 and MySQL 5 ... I think your enviroment is too new...

Comment: @Daniele  The application works perfectly with Oracle. Only when I point my db to mysql8, I get above error. All other environment components remain the same.

Comment: Ok, then check the mysql jar driver embedded in tomcab/lib/ext and update it  to cover mysql 8. But be care, as @olak said, mysql 8 is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Liferay CE 6.1.1 was released in Feb 2013, MySQL 8 in April 2018. It's safe to assume that Liferay 6.1 hasn't been tested on MySQL 8.

Java 8 was released in March 2014. Same assumption here.

Even Liferay 6.1 EE, which saw releases much later, doesn't [list MySQL 8](https://web.liferay.com/services/support/compatibility-matrix) compatibility. While it lists Java 8 support, that support came in with a later version - definitely one that was published after the Java 8 release date.

Instead of downgrading your runtime environment, I'd suggest to keep your customer-facing application, e.g. Liferay, current. Benefit not only from new features, but also from bugfixes.

Note that even Liferay DXP 7.1 (the enterprise version) doesn't list MySQL 8 as supported. It came out just after MySQL 8 release, and during the release cycle, there was no more time to certify MySQL 8. I'm expecting this compatibility for the next release, maybe backported to the 7.0 DXP branch.